# How to redirect site url to www in pligg

Tags: php

How redirect site url to www for `pligg`.I dont have more knowledge about `pligg`.So please provide me the help.

`example:http://example.com  to http://www.example.com`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Setting your site base to address without www**

edit .htaccess

replace

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

to

```
# Fix trailing slash problem
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+[^/])$ http://infoneo.pl/$1/ [R=301,L]
# Remove www., always.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.infoneo\.pl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://infoneo.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
##### Re-directing End #####
```

infoneo.pl change to your site base address

From: http://discussion.dreamhost.com/thread-87381.html

Comment: In admin there is any other change required?Thanks for reply